# How to find out classpath of Java projects

Tags: java, classpath

I have a few Java projects that I've downloaded form Github. How do I figure out the classpaths of these projects? I'm trying to run them on some source code analysis tools, and it's asking for the classpath due to unresolved classes.

fyi I'm trying out on WebGoat 8.0/7.1, and OWASP Benchmark, which are Maven projects.

Comment: Are these Java projects using a build model such as Maven or Gradle?

Comment: The ones mentioned above are Maven projects. Updated original post to reflect this.

Comment: What happens when you do a Maven build?  The whole thing should be fairly automatic, at least this is what I would expect.

Comment: mvn compile successfuly completes. I'm not asking about building though. I'm trying to load the source files into a source code analysis tool (HPE Fortify) using the scan wizard, and it's complaining of unresolved classes and  asking for the classpath.

Comment: Hmm...I would go about this by loading the project into a heavy duty IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, which would then handle classpath issues for me automatically.  Is there something particular about your tool that you can't use something else like a more standard IDE?

Comment: Tried maven fortify plugin?

Comment: Maybe this helps, too: ``mvn dependency:build-classpath``

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani thanks I didn't even know there's such a thing. So ok, I'm trying to install the maven plugin, and the instructions to install the binary are to navigate to the root directory then run "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pom.xml -DpomFile=pom.xml", so I navigate to the WebGoat project root directory and run the command, but I get a build failure with the error "The specified file 'Webgoat\pom' not exists.

Comment: @Matt weird. mvn compile successfully completes, but mvn dependency:build-classpath causes a build failure, could not resolve dependencies for project org.owasp.webgoat.lesson:webgoat-lessons-parent:pom:8.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.owasp.webgoat:webgoat-container:jar:8.0-SNAPSHOT, org.owasp.webgoat:webgoat-container:jar:tests:8.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.owasp.webgoat:webgoat-container:jar:8.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @user1118764 Is webgoat possibly not a compile time dependency? Furthermore, since webgoat v8 is not available in the Maven repos, are you sure that your github repository configuration is correct?

Comment: @Matt I'm simply following the build instructions at the WebGoat website at https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat